# Android studio - When connected to a bluetooth device, the onDestroy is called

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, mediacontroller

I'm working on a music application and I've noticed that when a bluetooth device is connected or disconnected, the activity destructor is called, which causes the music to stop playing. I've tried other music apps but it doesn't happen with them, connecting the device does not interrupt the music. I made a new android app but the same thing happens.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[Android studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmaX9.png)

[The bluetooth device image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfF1J.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367910/prevent-ondestroy-when-bluetooth-connection-state-changes?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help  you should close the question now

Comment: Unfortunately I can't close the question.